# Ruby on Rails; Form id tag Will not Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and I recently started a new Rails project where I am attempting to use an existing database. While creating the model for this database I used some symbols `(:emid, :sid, :conid, :emnum, :tc, :emac)` in my `new.html.erb` file to identify the form fields. I did not realize that these had to match the names of the database columns. I changed them to what they are now `("employee_id", "supplier_id", "contractor_id", "employee_number", "trade_code", "employee_active")`, but the html page that loads does not change. The id attribute for the inputs of the form will not update even though I've changed all of them.

Model (employee.rb):

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "Employee"
  def change
    create_table "Employee", primary_key: :"employee_id", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.integer "supplier_id",     limit: 4,              null: false
      t.integer "contractor_id",   limit: 4,              null: false
      t.string  "employee_number",   limit: 45,             null: false
      t.string  "trade_code",      limit: 45,             null: false
      t.integer "employee_active",    limit: 1,  default: 1, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field "employee_id" %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_field "supplier_id" %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_field "contractor_id" %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_field "employee_number" %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_field "trade_code" %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_field "employee_active" %>
    </p>
```

Error output from browser:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"y9UsuK6rc9qdhy/e0WPUJiT5rzw1QQqDuGpIVl4l4sUpVP2ZUm6Yak3/GImT8niSt5wbyf43OUGH1FrzulylQA==",
"employee"=>{"emid"=>"",
"sid"=>"666",
"conid"=>"66",
"emnum"=>"f",
"tc"=>"f",
"emac"=>"1"},
"commit"=>"Save Employee"}
```

Controller:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(e_params)

    @employee.save
    redirect_to @employee
  end
  private
    def e_params
      params.require(:employee).permit("employee_id", "supplier_id", "contractor_id", "employee_number", "trade_code", "employee_active")
    end
end
```

HTML Source:

```
<p>
    <label for="employee_title">Title</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="employee[emid]" id="employee_emid" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="employee_text">Text</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="employee[sid]" id="employee_sid" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="employee_text">Text</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="employee[conid]" id="employee_conid" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="employee_text">Text</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="employee[emnum]" id="employee_emnum" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="employee_text">Text</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="employee[tc]" id="employee_tc" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="employee_text">Text</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="employee[emac]" id="employee_emac" />
    </p>
```

Because of this, I get the error:
``` Mysql2::Error: Field 'supplier_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO ``Employee`` VALUES () ```
I am assuming this is because my model can't recognize what the html forms are and can't get the information from it.

How do I get the id attributes to update to what they are now?

Comment: Why do you have the body of a migration file in employee.rb? If you use a custom primary key you'll also need this in employee.rb: 'set_primary_key :employee_id'

Comment: I was following a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@kitsched/starting-a-ruby-on-rails-project-from-existing-data-7dda5044c85f#.e4u70cz12) to use an existing database with a new rails project. @eeeeeean

Comment: If you run Employee.new in the rails console it will show you what your attributes are. The not null error for supplier_id indicates you're on the right track, but I'd ignore the form until you're sure your Employee object behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get around this by closing everything and restarting my computer. I'm sure it wasn't the best way to to this, but it got the job done. When I started the server again and checked the id tags from page source they all had the updated values from the `new.html.erb` file.